# How to publish message to Limited endpoint AWS SNS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

How do i send notification to limited end point by using AWS SNS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it will be really helpful for everyone, if  you could tell us 'I am facing this problem while sending notification using AWS SNS using these steps'

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "limited end point" ?

Comment: I have 100 endpoint but, i want send message to only 50 endpoint. is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe the desired end points to a topic and then publish to that topic so that only a set of end points receive the notification. You can visit these links to know more:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-topicmobile.html 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SubscribeTopic.html

-Rohan